# `keyof` reported compile error when using generic type

Tags: typescript

First I have a type definition map all properties into number by using `keyof`

```
type Numeric<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: number
}
```

Below is a class I will use.

```
class Entity {
    aNumber: number;
}
```

Below is a function which accept a generic type argument and a local variable with type `Numberic<T>`. But when I assigned `{ aNumber: 1 }` it gave a compile error.

```
const fn = <T extends Entity>() => {
    const n: Numeric<T> = {
//        ^
//        Type '{ aNumber: number; }' is not 
//        assignable to type 'Numeric<T>'
        aNumber: 1
    };
};
```

I don't know why `{ aNumber: number; }` cannot be assigned to `Numeric<T>` since the type argument `T` must be extended from `Entity` and it must contains a key named `aNumber`. This means `aNumber` must be the key of type T and should be able to assigned to `Numeric<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is misleading. However there is an error and that is what TypeScript is catching. Indeed there is nothing wrong with `Entity`:

```
type Numeric<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: number
}
interface Entity {
    aNumber: number
}

// No error
const n: Numeric<Entity> = {
    aNumber: 1
};
```

However when you say `T extends Entity` it opens it up for non number values e.g.

```
type Numeric<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: number
}
interface Entity {
    aNumber: number
}

// No error
const n: Numeric<Entity> = {
    aNumber: 1
};

interface X extends Entity {
    notANumber: string
}
// Error. Thank you TypeScript
const o: Numeric<X> = {
    aNumber: 1
};
```

Hence the error when you use a `T extends Entity` in `Numeric`.

Comment: No, I don't think your explanation is correct. I do see a bug in TS part, but not in your case. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The constraint imposed by `<T extends Entity>` should be considered just the *minimum requirement* that `T` should meet. It means "`T` should at least contain `aNumber: number` pair".

Let's see `const n: T`. It means "n should at least contains whatever key-value pairs that are in `T`".

Now we do know, `T` has a `aNumber: number` pair, but remember that's just the minimum requirement. `T` might as well be `{ aNumber: number; aString: string }`. That's why this will also give you error.

```
// if you understand this:
const n: { aNumber: number; aString: string } = { aNumber: 42 }  // error, of course
// you see why this is an error:
const n: T = { aNumber: 42 }  // also error
```

You can never tell what exactly is `T`. `keyof T` is fine though, cus we know about at least one of `T`'s key for sure.

```
const k: keyof T = "aNumber"
```

---

To prove my point, let's review a non-generic case. Take @basarat's code for example, here `X` is not genreic.

```
type Numeric<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: number
}

type OptionalNumeric<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: number
}

interface Entity {
    aNumber: number
}

interface X extends Entity {
    notANumber: string
}

// Error, because `notANumber` is missing
const o: Numeric<X> = { aNumber: 1 };
// Correct
const o1: Numeric<X> = { aNumber: 1, notANumber: 2 };
// Also correct, because all keys are optional.
const o2: OptionalNumeric<X> = { aNumber: 1 };
```

---

Side note. Above should explain your case. However, I do believe there's a bug in TS.

I think if you use `OptionalNumeric` in your original case, what you want should work. But turns out it doesn't. Should be a defect when generic type parameters involve.

Comment: the error still there even though I used `type Numeric<T> = { [K in keyof T]?: number }`. But if I'm passing a type argument in `Numeric<T>` it works well such as `const n: Numeric<Entity>`. But I'm using a generic argument, as what I did in the example `const fn = <T extends Entity>() => { const n: Numeric<T> = { aNumber: 1 }; };` it failed.

Comment: @ShaunXu I'm saying this a) what you're trying to do is wrong; b) optional key is supposed to work, but it doesn't and should be considered a bug. I only have explanation, not solution.

Comment: A workaround here is (assuming we use `OptionalNumeric`) is to assign `n` to the type `OptionalNumeric<T & Entity>` instead of `OptionalNumeric<T>`.  I don't know if the issue with `OptionalNumeric<T>` is known, though.

Comment: I thought this was related to [Microsoft/TypeScript#13442](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13442) but I guess it's not.